# Wifi behaving weird after installing ubuntu 14.04

Tags: wireless, drivers

I am using a compaq presario cq43 laptop. Initially I installed Ubuntu 12.04 and was using a broadcom wireless sta driver(BC4313) for Wi-Fi. It was working well, then after three years I installed Ubuntu 14.04. I'm having trouble with wifi now.
It only connects sometimes. After going through the Ubuntu forum discussions, I found a remedy.

Step 1:

- Go to additional driver under software update
- Select proprietary driver for broadcom
- If not selected and click
- apply changes

Step 2:

- `sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source`
- `sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree`

Step 3:

- Reboot

Now the issue is every time I restart my laptop I have to run the above steps and after rebooting the Wi-Fi works fine.
I have updated all the headers and software through software updater using LAN connection.

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 11 Aug 2014 15:33 IST +0530

Script from: 04 Aug 2014 18:47 UTC +0000

##### release #####

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty

##### kernel #####

Linux 3.13.0-32-generic #57-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 15 03:51:12 UTC 2014 i686 athlon i686 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop #####

Ubuntu

##### lspci #####

06:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:3577]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

07:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:4727] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:1795]
    Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge

##### lsusb #####

Bus 002 Device 002: ID 058f:a001 Alcor Micro Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

##### PCMCIA Card Info #####

##### rfkill #####

0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
1: hp-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
2: hp-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes

##### lsmod #####

hp_wmi                 13702  0 
sparse_keymap          13708  1 hp_wmi
wmi                    18673  1 hp_wmi
b43                   356470  0 
ssb                    51854  1 b43
brcmsmac              529837  0 
cordic                 12518  1 brcmsmac
brcmutil               15066  1 brcmsmac
bcma                   42043  3 b43,brcmsmac
mac80211              546051  2 b43,brcmsmac
cfg80211              409394  3 b43,brcmsmac,mac80211

##### interfaces #####

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig #####

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr   
          inet addr:192.168.0.100  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::461e:a1ff:fec5:b875/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:231 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:364 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:136089 (136.0 KB)  TX bytes:47961 (47.9 KB)

##### iwconfig #####

lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=off   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off


##### route #####

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0

##### resolv.conf #####

nameserver 127.0.1.1

##### nm-tool #####

NetworkManager Tool

State: connected (global)

- Device: wlan0 ----------------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              802.11 WiFi
  Driver:            brcmsmac
  State:             unavailable
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        

  Capabilities:

  Wireless Properties
    WEP Encryption:  yes
    WPA Encryption:  yes
    WPA2 Encryption: yes

  Wireless Access Points 

- Device: eth0  [Wired connection 1] -------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            r8169
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes
  HW Address:        

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes
    Speed:           100 Mb/s

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         on

  IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         192.168.0.100
    Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
    Gateway:         192.168.0.1

    DNS:             192.168.0.1

##### NetworkManager.state #####

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf #####

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### iw reg get #####

country 00:
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (3, 20)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (3, 20), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5170 - 5250 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5735 - 5835 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS

##### iwlist channels #####

lo        no frequency information.

eth0      no frequency information.

wlan0     13 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz

##### iwlist scan #####

wlan0     Interface doesn't support scanning : Network is down

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

eth0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

##### module infos #####

[b43]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-32-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/b43/b43.ko
firmware:       b43/ucode9.fw
firmware:       b43/ucode5.fw
firmware:       b43/ucode16_mimo.fw
firmware:       b43/ucode15.fw
firmware:       b43/ucode14.fw
firmware:       b43/ucode13.fw
firmware:       b43/ucode11.fw
license:        GPL
author:         Rafał Miłecki
author:         Gábor Stefanik
author:         Michael Buesch
author:         Stefano Brivio
author:         Martin Langer
description:    Broadcom B43 wireless driver
srcversion:     42BAE2DB9BADE3E7ECA2CC0
alias:          bcma:m04BFid0812rev1Dcl*
alias:          bcma:m04BFid0812rev18cl*
alias:          bcma:m04BFid0812rev17cl*
alias:          bcma:m04BFid0812rev11cl*
alias:          ssb:v4243id0812rev10*
alias:          ssb:v4243id0812rev0F*
alias:          ssb:v4243id0812rev0D*
alias:          ssb:v4243id0812rev0C*
alias:          ssb:v4243id0812rev0B*
alias:          ssb:v4243id0812rev0A*
alias:          ssb:v4243id0812rev09*
alias:          ssb:v4243id0812rev07*
alias:          ssb:v4243id0812rev06*
alias:          ssb:v4243id0812rev05*
depends:        bcma,ssb,mac80211,cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-32-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 686 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        A7:FC:65:90:FC:4A:8D:85:9A:AE:BD:A2:CA:5D:D0:47:16:24:4F:A0
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           bad_frames_preempt:enable(1) / disable(0) Bad Frames Preemption (int)
parm:           fwpostfix:Postfix for the .fw files to load. (string)
parm:           hwpctl:Enable hardware-side power control (default off) (int)
parm:           nohwcrypt:Disable hardware encryption. (int)
parm:           hwtkip:Enable hardware tkip. (int)
parm:           qos:Enable QOS support (default on) (int)
parm:           btcoex:Enable Bluetooth coexistence (default on) (int)
parm:           verbose:Log message verbosity: 0=error, 1=warn, 2=info(default), 3=debug (int)
parm:           pio:Use PIO accesses by default: 0=DMA, 1=PIO (int)
parm:           allhwsupport:Enable support for all hardware (even it if overlaps with the brcmsmac driver) (int)

[ssb]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-32-generic/kernel/drivers/ssb/ssb.ko
license:        GPL
description:    Sonics Silicon Backplane driver
srcversion:     3DE188310F77C566C2E8CB3
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004350sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d0000432Csv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d0000432Bsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004329sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004328sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004325sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004324sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d0000A8D6sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004322sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004321sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004320sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004319sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014A4d00004318sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004318sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004315sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004312sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004311sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004307sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004306sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004301sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-32-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 686 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        A7:FC:65:90:FC:4A:8D:85:9A:AE:BD:A2:CA:5D:D0:47:16:24:4F:A0
sig_hashalgo:   sha512

[brcmsmac]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-32-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/brcm80211/brcmsmac/brcmsmac.ko
firmware:       brcm/bcm43xx_hdr-0.fw
firmware:       brcm/bcm43xx-0.fw
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Broadcom 802.11n wireless LAN driver.
author:         Broadcom Corporation
srcversion:     43D6897F7EB716081DF69BE
alias:          bcma:m04BFid0812rev18cl*
alias:          bcma:m04BFid0812rev17cl*
alias:          bcma:m04BFid0812rev11cl*
depends:        bcma,mac80211,brcmutil,cfg80211,cordic
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-32-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 686 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        A7:FC:65:90:FC:4A:8D:85:9A:AE:BD:A2:CA:5D:D0:47:16:24:4F:A0
sig_hashalgo:   sha512

[brcmutil]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-32-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/brcm80211/brcmutil/brcmutil.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Broadcom 802.11n wireless LAN driver utilities.
author:         Broadcom Corporation
srcversion:     E81EE4CBB6A7A689150D93D
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-32-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 686 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        A7:FC:65:90:FC:4A:8D:85:9A:AE:BD:A2:CA:5D:D0:47:16:24:4F:A0
sig_hashalgo:   sha512

[bcma]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-32-generic/kernel/drivers/bcma/bcma.ko
license:        GPL
description:    Broadcom's specific AMBA driver
srcversion:     E41B811D88783DD5BC38565
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004727sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004365sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004359sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004358sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004357sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004353sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004331sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d0000A8D8sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004313sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00000576sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-32-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 686 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        A7:FC:65:90:FC:4A:8D:85:9A:AE:BD:A2:CA:5D:D0:47:16:24:4F:A0
sig_hashalgo:   sha512

##### module parameters #####

[b43]
allhwsupport: 0
bad_frames_preempt: 0
btcoex: 1
hwpctl: 0
hwtkip: 0
nohwcrypt: 0
pio: 0
qos: 1
verbose: 2

##### /etc/modules #####

lp
brcmsmac
brcmsmac
brcmsmac
brcmsmac
b43
b43

##### blacklists #####

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac
blacklist b43
blacklist wl
blacklist b43
blacklist wl
blacklist b43
blacklist wl
blacklist b43
blacklist wl
blacklist b43
blacklist wl

##### udev rules #####

# PCI device 0x10ec:0x8136 (r8169)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"

# PCI device 0x14e4:0x4727 (brcmsmac)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan0"

##### dmesg #####

[   14.492780] bcma: bus0: Found chip with id 0x4313, rev 0x01 and package 0x08
[   14.492818] bcma: bus0: Core 0 found: ChipCommon (manuf 0x4BF, id 0x800, rev 0x24, class 0x0)
[   14.492843] bcma: bus0: Core 1 found: IEEE 802.11 (manuf 0x4BF, id 0x812, rev 0x18, class 0x0)
[   14.492889] bcma: bus0: Core 2 found: PCIe (manuf 0x4BF, id 0x820, rev 0x11, class 0x0)
[   14.505581] bcma: bus0: Bus registered
[   14.617110] brcmsmac bcma0:0: mfg 4bf core 812 rev 24 class 0 irq 23
[   14.838616] ieee80211 phy0: registered radio enabled led device: brcmsmac-phy0:radio gpio: 243
[   15.165326] type=1400 audit(1407751129.533:3): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=350 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   15.175540] type=1400 audit(1407751129.545:5): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=350 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   19.718493] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[  131.249919] brcmsmac bcma0:0: brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: qos enabled: false (implement)
[  131.249989] brcmsmac bcma0:0: brcms_ops_config: change power-save mode: false (implement)
[  131.250768] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[  131.737890] usb 4-2: Direct firmware load failed with error -2
[  131.739884] Bluetooth: can't load firmware, may not work correctly
[  133.207205] wlan0: authenticate with 
[  133.210575] wlan0: send auth to  (try 1/3)
[  133.238251] wlan0: send auth to  (try 2/3)
[  133.333829] wlan0: send auth to  (try 3/3)
[  133.432728] wlan0: authentication with  timed out

########## wireless info END ############
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

Answer (score 0):

Do:

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source

sudo -i
echo "blacklist b43" >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
echo "blacklist ssb" >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
exit

gksudo gedit /etc/modules
```

Then leave only one `brcmsmac` and completely remove all instances of `b43` save the file.
You may have to install gksu, it is not installed by default any more.

Also it is showing a hardblock this usually means the wireless is turned of by a physical switch or a key combination like FN+F2.
Reboot

Comment: i have tried the above codes but in vain..problem persists...i am running the 3 steps to connect wifi after each restart.

Comment: Please run the script that is in the accepted answer in the link below so we may see the information needed to help diagnose the issue.
<http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-can-i-do>

Comment: i have run the script with lan connected and wireles-info.txt is generated.

Comment: i have posted the output as an answer...plz guide me what to do next?